# Что лучше использовать и почему? Private/public переменные

Tags: c#, unity3d

Конечно, проще сделать так:

```
public int _maxHP;
public int _maxMana;
```

Но можно сделать так:

```
[SerializeField] private int _maxHP;
[SerializeField] private int _maxMana;

public int GetMaxHP { get { return _maxHP; } }
public int GetMaxMana { get { return _maxMana; } }
```

Стоит ли вообще заморачиваться и постоянно делать по второму способу?

P.S. данные постоянно используются то там, то сям в разных скриптах.

Comment: `public int maxHP {get;}` ? Или `{get; protected set;}`

Comment: Если вы думаете об этом в терминах "private vs public мне использовать" —  то ответ (та-дам!) очевиден: скрывайте, если нет необходимости снаружи класса. Но вы не видите другого аспекта вопроса: вы думаете "почему бы не использовать поля вместо свойств" (ну точнее вы даже не осознаёте пока разницу между полями и свойствами (не назывете их, не знаете краткой формы записи) и не понимаете, чем так плохо делать полями то, что нужно делать свойствами. Так что на мой взгляд предложенный в качестве дубликата вопрос вам когда-нибудь пригодится, когда дозреете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда ты используешь private переменные, то ты не захламляешь "интерфейс" класса лишней информацией.

Каждую публичную переменную ты должен проверять на корректность прежде чем использовать, а вот при работе с private переменной ты работаешь на своей территории и некоторые проверки ты можешь опустить.

Делая какие-то поля публичными, ты нарушаешь инкапсуляцию и дает представление о внутренней реализации класса.

В общем, публичным должно быть то, что действительно должно быть публичным.

Comment: Можно пример того что ДОЛЖНО быть публичным?

Comment: @DeadLord зависит от ситуации... Ну скажем, у тебя есть класс Person и тебе надо хранить возраст пользователя Age. Если ты сделаешь просто поле публичным, то пользователь сможет вбить туда отрицательный возраст или очень большое число далекое от реальности => можно сделать публичное свойство, где будет проверка допустимости значения.

Comment: Если у тебя в классе будет все публичным и без проверок, то ты вечно должен будешь держать в голове различные правила, а так ты спрятал правило, что возраст не должен быть отрицательным и если ошибешься где, то сразу вылетит ошибка при присвоении.

Comment: Благодарю! Действительно полезно)

Answer (score 1):

`[SerializeField]` только для тех полей, которые ты задаеш через инспектор, но не используются никем другим, как например ссылка на префаб `[SerializeField] private GameObject _objectTamplate;` или компоненты дочерних объектов в префабе `[SerializeField] private Text _text`.

`public` можно использовать по разному, например: `public int Value { get; private set; }` или `protected set` для наследников. В случаях когда, изменения только внутри класса и его кто-то должен читать, без возможности менять. Раздельные поле и свойство (`get/set`) только в случаях, когда поле сериализовано.

Для массивов изменяемых только внутри, но публично читаемые:

```
private String[] myArr = { "The", "quick", "brown", "fox" };
public IList<String> myList = Array.AsReadOnly(myArr);
```

`private` поля это исключительно внутренняя кухня класса.